# How to delete all views from MySQL database using MySQL query/command?

Tags: mysql, database, view

I need to delete all views from my MySQL database. How can I do that using query?

Can anyone can help me please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quoting from [MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/drop-view.html):

```
DROP VIEW [IF EXISTS]
    view_name [, view_name] ...
    [RESTRICT | CASCADE]
```

`DROP VIEW` removes one or more views. You must have the `DROP` privilege for each view. If any of the views named in the argument list do not exist, MySQL returns an error indicating by name which non-existing views it was unable to drop, but it also drops all of the views in the list that do exist.

The `IF EXISTS` clause prevents an error from occurring for views that don't exist. When this clause is given, a `NOTE` is generated for each nonexistent view. See *Section 12.7.5.41, “SHOW WARNINGS Syntax”*.

`RESTRICT` and `CASCADE`, if given, are parsed and ignored.

Comment: I think he's asking how to drop all in an automated fashion. Not how to manually lookup and write a drop statement for an arbitrary number of views.

Answer (score 24):

I've been using this one:

```
/* DROP ALL VIEWS */

SET @views = NULL;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(table_schema, '.', table_name) INTO @views
 FROM information_schema.views 
 WHERE table_schema = @database_name; -- Your DB name here 

SET @views = IFNULL(CONCAT('DROP VIEW ', @views), 'SELECT "No Views"');
PREPARE stmt FROM @views;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: Nice script, thx. And because of GROUP_CONCAT, something like SET GLOBAL  group_concat_max_len = 1000000; could be usefull.

Comment: I had to `set @@group_concat_max_len = 100000;` for this to work! If you have a 100 views, and schema name plus view name is longer than 10 characters, you easily pass the default 1024 limit.

Comment: This almost worked for me, but my database name had a hyphen in it.  I had to wrap the `table_schema` in backticks:
`SELECT GROUP_CONCAT('\`',table_schema, '\`.', table_name)`
There might also be cases where you need to do the same to the `table_name`

Answer (score 2):

try this untested code

```
DECLARE VIEW_NAME VARCHAR(31); 
DECLARE VIEW_NAMES CURSOR 
FOR 
SELECT table_name 
FROM information_schema.views; 
WHERE table_schema = 'DB_Name'
OPEN VIEW_NAMES; 
REPEAT 
FETCH VIEW_NAMES INTO VIEW_NAME; 
DROP VIEW VIEW_NAME     
UNTIL done END REPEAT; 
CLOSE VIEW_NAMES; 
END;
```

Comment: that will drop all the views on a server, not in one db :)

Answer (score -1):

Here's a Ruby method that will do what you want:

```
# @param [Array] databases, e.g. ['db1', 'db2']
  def drop_all_views(databases)
    views = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT CONCAT(TABLE_SCHEMA,'.',TABLE_NAME) FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'VIEW' AND TABLE_SCHEMA IN('#{databases.join("', '")}');")

    views = views.to_a.flatten

    # Then drop all of those views from their respective databases
    views.each do |v|
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("DROP VIEW IF EXISTS #{v};")
    end
  end
```